# Ubuntu POS printer manual set-up and image printing

Tags: java, ubuntu, printing, ubuntu-16.04, linux-device-driver

I have Thermal Receipt Printer model `RP58E` from Xiamen Rongta Technology. I know this one doesn't have drivers for Linux, but I managed to set it up manually. What I did: Printers -> Add Printer -> Selected `Unknown` -> Forward -> under select printer from database I chose `Generic (recommended)` -> Forward -> here I chose `text-only (recommended)` and then finished. But this way I can only print Text and not images and I'd like to print images as well. Is there anyway I can achieve this?
I'm making a Java program for the printing, I wrote it like this:

```
public void printImage(String printerName, String imgLocation) throws PrintException, IOException {
        DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PNG;
        PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        aset.add(new PrinterResolution(205, 205, PrinterResolution.DPI));
        aset.add(new MediaPrintableArea(0, 0, 48, 48, MediaPrintableArea.MM));
        PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
        for(PrintService printService : services) {
            if(printService.getName().equals(printerName)) {
                DocPrintJob pj = printService.createPrintJob();
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(imgLocation);
                Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(fis, flavor, null);
                pj.print(doc, aset);
            }
        }
    }
```

Can I somehow print images if I have `text-only (recommended)` set-up for printer?

EDDIT: Here are screenshots of options to choose from when setting up printer:

[image: options1]

[image: options2]

Comment: If it says text only why would you expect it to print images? Is there a text and images option?

Comment: @mwarren yes, there is bunch of options to choose from. text-only (recommended) is the option I went with, because it was recommended. I'll add a picture of options to the question.

Comment: I expect it is the recommended option as it is the most likely to work, other options might work as well, they are just not guaranteed to work.

Comment: @mwarren yes, I allready tried with PDF and PostScript and it didn't work. I always just prints random stuff. I eddited the question and added pictures.

Comment: I would first check with the printer manufacturers website and see what formats the printer supports. You may have better luck with PCL or GDI, but check what the printer supports first.

Comment: The website says there is a linux driver available. Have you tried their driver download page?

Comment: @mwarren there is no linux driver for this one

Comment: Does your printer support PCL language? Why do you choose it?

Comment: Have you looked for PPD file in the downloaded CD image?

Comment: @user3029612 Hmm.. There spec sheet for the printer says a linux driver is available.

Comment: @0andriy yes I did and had no luck. I did solve the problem thou, but I used 3rd party printer drivers.

Comment: So, share what you did as an answer. Or append this information to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a fix to this drivers problem by installing
https://github.com/klirichek/zj-58
this driver.

I found out, that most thermal printers have the same commands for printing, so it has little to no change. The only problem I've noticed so far is that the text printed is a bit larger than with original drivers.